# Усовершенствованный метод Крамера с++

Tags: c++, алгоритм, функции

Здравствуйте, решил переделать код для метода Крамера. Точнее, лучше оформить и ввести условие, если определитель матрици равен 0. Но еще до введения этого условия возникла ошибка. Компилится код, ввожу с клавиатуры значения, и тут перед выводом решения `Invalid Floating point operation`. Я так понимаю, ошибка с плавающей запятой, а в чем конкретнее она состоит. Объясните, пожалуйста.

```
    #include <conio.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <vcl.h>
    #include <iostream>
    #pragma hdrstop

    char bufCur[256];
    char* Cur(const char* text)
    {
            CharToOem(text, bufCur);
            return bufCur;
    }

    float vizn(float arr[][3])
    {
            float vizn,p1,p2,p3;
            p1=arr[0][0]*arr[1][1]*arr[2][2]+arr[2][0]*arr[0][1]*arr[1][2];
            p2=arr[0][2]*arr[1][0]*arr[2][1]-arr[2][0]*arr[1][1]*arr[0][2];
            p3=-arr[0][0]*arr[2][1]*arr[1][2]-arr[1][0]*arr[0][1]*arr[2][2];
            vizn=p1+p2+p3;
            return vizn;
    }

    #pragma argsused
    int main(int argc, char* argv[])
    {
            float A[3][3];
            int i, j;
            float B[3],V_A,x1,x2,x3,V_m_1,V_m_2,V_m_3,m_1[3][3],m_2[3][3],m_3[3][3];

            V_A=vizn(A);

            printf(Cur("Введiть даннi в розширену матрицю:\n"));
            for (i=0;i<3;i++)
            {
             for(j=0;j<3;j++)
             {
              printf("A[%d][%d]=",i,j);
              scanf("%f",&A[i][j]);
             }
            }
            for (i=0;i<3;i++)
            {
              printf("B[%d]=",i);
              scanf("%f",&B[i]);
            }
            clrscr();

            printf(Cur("\nРозширена матриця\n\n"));
            for(i=0;i<3;i++)
            {
                    for(j=0;j<3;j++)
                    {
                            printf ("%.2f\t",A[i][j]);
                    }
                    printf("%.2f",B[i]);
                    printf("\n");
            }
            for(i=0;i<3;i++)
            {
                    for(j=0;j<3;j++)
                    {
                            m_1[i][j]=A[i][j];
                            m_2[i][j]=A[i][j];
                            m_3[i][j]=A[i][j];
                    }
            }
            for(i=0;i<3;i++)
            {
                    m_1[i][0]=B[i];
                    m_2[i][1]=B[i];
                    m_3[i][2]=B[i];
            }
            V_m_1=vizn(m_1);
            V_m_2=vizn(m_2);
            V_m_3=vizn(m_3);
            x1=V_m_1/V_A;////////////////здесь выбивает
            x2=V_m_2/V_A;
            x3=V_m_3/V_A;
            printf(Cur("\nРозв'язок"));
            printf("\n\nx1=%.2f\nx2=%.2f\nx3=%.2f",x1,x2,x3);
            getch();
            return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Хм... Программа берет совершенно неинициализированную матрицу `A`, т.е. матрицу, заполненную бессмысленным непредсказуемым "мусором", и вычисляет ее определитель в строке

```
V_A=vizn(A);
```

В результате значение `V_A` тоже является бессмысленным непредсказуемым мусором. И это вам еще "повезло" (а скорее - не повезло), ибо программа могла упасть уже тут.

Только после этого программа вдруг начинает запрашивать у пользователя осмысленные значения для элементов матрицы `A`.

Неудивительно, что потом, ниже по коду, попытка деления на какое-то непредсказуемое бессмысленное значение `V_A` приводит к падению программы с Invalid Floating point operation.

Почему вы пытаетесь вычислять определитель `A` еще до того, как в `A` введены осмысленные значения? С точки зрения банального здравого смысла ведь должно быть понятно, что *сначала* надо заполнить матрицу `A` осмысленными значениями, а уж только *потом* пытаться вычислять ее определитель.

Comment: точно, тогда мне просто надо написать V_A=vizn(A); ниже кода ввода  єлементов массива?

Comment: @craftyperson: Совершенно верно. Это не гарантирует того, что ваша программа заработает (могут быть еще ошибки), но это - первое, что бросается в глаза.

Comment: выполнил, а в итоге то самое(

Comment: @craftyperson: Ищите ошибки дальше. Я уже вижу, что ваша функция вычисления определителя `vizn` написана неправильно. Т.е. она просто не соответствует обычной формуле определителя 3x3 из любого учебника. Откуда вы взяли эти ваши формулы?

Comment: нужно написать произведение главной диагонали на триугольеники , основы которых паралельны ей и отнять произведение побочной и треугольников , основы которых паралельны ей? ок

Comment: Подождите, может я и не прав и `vizn` написана правильно. (Проверить не помешает) Вы уверены, что матрица, которую вы вводите, не обладает определителем `0`? Если определитель равен нулю, то будет ошибка Floating Point из-за деления на `0`. Добавьте в код отладочную печать для `V_A` и посмотрите, на что вы делите.

Comment: все должно работать нормально

Comment: нашел проверенные значения для ситемы, определитель не равен 0. но выбивает ошибку

Comment: Посмотрите уже наконец-то в отладчике какое значение в V_A, и почему оно такое получается. Здесь нет телепатов!

Comment: @craftyperson: Ну уж не знаю, что  там у вас происходит. Я сделал вышеописанное исправление, запустил вашу программу на заранее подготовленной системе и получил совершенно правильное решение, без каких-либо floating point errors. Почему у вас там что-то вылетает нам отсюда, к сожалению, не видно...

Comment: Ок, попробую еще раз

Comment: Спасибо все заработало, просто перезагрузил ноут заново запустил и работает)

Comment: а если я хочу ввести условие где определитель равен 0: if(V_A==0) {printf(Cur("Розв. немає"));return } else{//код для вычисления ршения//}

Comment: скажите что в таком случает должен возвращать return

Comment: если определитель 0 , то вводим текст на экран и прекращаем находить решение, в ином случае находим его. тогда правильно написана эта часть кода?

Comment: уже понял там должно біть условие:if(V_A==0) {printf(Cur("Розв'язкiв немає бо визначник дорівнює нулю"));getch();return 0;}
            else{.....}